# mod rewrite to remove the file name from url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

If I have a file, let's say `rec-view.php`, then I can call it by this URL:

```
domain.com/record/rec-view.php?id=3
```

However, I want to call this file with the following URL as well:

```
domain.com/record/3
```

So, basically I want to tell the server that if there is any file that ends with the "**-view.php**" name, then it should remove the file name all together in the URL and open that file only by passing the id.

I am trying the following rule, it accesses the file by "/v" but I need to access by the **dynamic number**.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/v$ $1-view.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    # Match the host, if you wish
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$

    RewriteRule record/(\d) /record/rec-view.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

You can [test it online](http://htaccess.mwl.be/), if you wish.

[image]

With `(\d)` you're only matching against numeric values, if you wish to accept any values, you may change it to `(.*)`.

Just saw that you need a more generic rule:

```
# Maps record/4 to record/record-view.php?id=4
RewriteRule (.*)/(\d) /$1/$1-view.php?id=$2 [NC,L]
```

For this to work, you need a more strict naming convention in place. More specifically, you need all those `*-view.php` files to be named exactly like their containing directory.

There's no way to get `rec` prefix out of thin air unless it's always the first 3 characters; is it?

### Update

As per your comment, here's a more generic ruleset that checks if the URI's last segment is a number and if so, then it maps the request to the containing directory's `*-view.php` file while maintaining the directory structure and appending the `?id=*` query string:

```
# This rule maps this:
#     domain.com/foo/bar/baz/4 
# to: 
#     domain.com/foo/bar/baz/baz-view.php?id=4
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(\d)$ /$1/$2/$2-view.php?id=$3 [L,R]
```

There are other variations that you might have wanted:

```
# This rule maps this:
#     domain.com/foo/bar/baz/4 
# to: 
#     domain.com/foo/bar/baz-view.php?id=4
#
# Notice the baz/ segment dropped.
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(\d)$ /$1/$2-view.php?id=$3 [L,R]

# This rule maps this:
#     domain.com/foo/bar/baz/4 
# to: 
#     domain.com/baz-view.php?id=4
#
# Notice all the segments dropped. Mapping to 
# a php file in the root directory. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(\d)$ /$2-view.php?id=$3 [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your edited generic rule is what I'm looking for. However it will work only if the url format is exactly like this `http://localhost/record/1`, but not in this case `http://localhost/a/b/record/1` etc. Is it possible to define the rule that if there is a number at the end of the url (for example `/1`) then map to the file with name that is in url before the id (and add `-view.php?id=xx`). For example if the url ends with `/record/1`, map it to `record-view.php?id=1` and if it ends with `/abc/2` map it to `abc-view.php?id=2`. Hope it makes sense, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```bsh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) $1-view.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the job **but** it also matches the rule when there is no id in the end. For example `domain.com/record/`. I want it to match only if there is an id after the `/record/`. Is it possible to do that without specifying the word `record` so that it's a more general rule.

Comment: It does not take care of the directory structure. For example, it rewrites `domain.com/record/3` to `domain.com/record-view.php?id=3` which is wrong.